# Why won't some mruby examples compile?

Tags: ruby, gcc, mruby

I've been trying to get mruby set up for use in C, but I've only had success compiling a simple "hello world" example. Other examples won't compile: when I try to compile https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/tools/mrbc/mrbc.c, I get this:

```
gcc -Iinclude hello.c libmruby_core.a libmruby.a -lm -o hello
hello.c: In function ‘parse_args’:
hello.c:119:24: error: ‘DUMP_DEBUG_INFO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         args->flags |= DUMP_DEBUG_INFO;
                        ^
hello.c:119:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
hello.c:122:23: error: ‘DUMP_ENDIAN_BIG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         args->flags = DUMP_ENDIAN_BIG | (args->flags & DUMP_DEBUG_INFO);
                       ^
hello.c:125:23: error: ‘DUMP_ENDIAN_LIL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         args->flags = DUMP_ENDIAN_LIL | (args->flags & DUMP_DEBUG_INFO);
                       ^
hello.c:154:57: error: ‘DUMP_ENDIAN_MASK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (args->verbose && args->initname && (args->flags & DUMP_ENDIAN_MASK) == 0) {
```

When I try to compile the 'more complex example' from http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2012/04/25/getting-started-with-mruby/, in the way they suggest (`gcc -Iinclude hello.c lib/libmruby.a -lm -o hello.out`) (actually: in a similar way. I've tried both ways.) I get this:

```
gcc -Iinclude hello.c libmruby.a -lm -o hellohello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:17:7: error: too few arguments to function ‘mrb_parse_string’
   p = mrb_parse_string(mrb, code);
       ^
In file included from /home/neo/Projects/MrubyHs/mruby-1.1.0/include/mruby/irep.h:14:0,
                 from /home/neo/Projects/MrubyHs/mruby-1.1.0/include/mruby/proc.h:10,
                 from hello.c:6:
/home/neo/Projects/MrubyHs/mruby-1.1.0/include/mruby/compile.h:170:34: note: declared here
 MRB_API struct mrb_parser_state* mrb_parse_string(mrb_state*,const char*,mrbc_context*);
                                  ^
hello.c:19:5: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
   n = mrb_generate_code(mrb, p);
     ^
hello.c:20:37: error: ‘mrb_state’ has no member named ‘irep’
   mrb_run(mrb, mrb_proc_new(mrb, mrb->irep[n]), mrb_top_self(mrb));
                                     ^
```

Looks like I'm missing some file or something, but I'm not sure what.
I'm using mruby 1.1.0. I have mruby-1.1.0/include which contains mrbconf.h, mruby.h, and a folder mruby in the gcc search path, and mruby-1.1.0/build/host/lib in LIBRARY_PATH (even though in my examples of what went wrong I just put them in the same folder as where I'm compiling).

Any idea what's wrong with my installation and/or how I'm compiling?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compile a newer version of `mrbc.c` with an older version of mruby. Those `#define`s were added [after 1.1.0 was released](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/commit/bc9c47d5180ab28e1a3db4dca80da7512aa6839a). It works for me if I use the version of mruby currently in the git repo:

```
$ make
...
$ gcc -Iinclude build/host/lib/libmruby.a mrbc.c
$ ./a.out
./a.out: no program file given
```

As for the second problem, `mrb_parse_string` was changed to accept an `mrb_context*` as the third argument [in July 2012](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/commit/65096c4c1bd1bfb6f547808fc01ab6ea223d9dc6#diff-b66c071679c8425c7257d935ea5e8edeL93), so you may want to look into updating your code to use the new API.

Comment: Now I get something else (this is with the most recent from Github and also with the mrbc that it comes with): http://pastebin.com/3i3nCXaC

I also built it just with "make"

Comment: Update: I'm pretty sure everything's installed properly; all the tests ran fine. Still want to know why I can't compile these, but I'm sure it's just because I didn't do my homework: I'll figure it out. Probably should be using the included "rakefile". Don't want to waste anybody's time.

Thanks a lot though.

Comment: Does `nm <path to libmruby.a>` print the names of those symbols?

Comment: Yep, they're all in there